# How can I set supported languages in a Fiori application?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

When we have a stand alone app that has index.html we can have something like data-sap-ui-xx-supportedLanguages="en,de" in the bootstrapping part to determine which languages are implemented in our app. In this case we will not see anymore an error like this:

> https://webidetestingXXX.dispatcher.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/i18n/i18n_en_US.properties 404

because we determined that our app does not support `en_US`!

How can I do the same in a Fiori type application, I mean when we don't have any index.html and it has only `Component.js` as the starting point!

I remember in the past we set that in `manifest.json`, but I am not sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned under the chapter **Supported Locales and Fallback Locale** in this documentation: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/ec753bc539d748f689e3ac814e129563

```
{
    "sap.ui5": {
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "myapp.i18n.i18n",
                    "supportedLocales": ["de", "en"],
                    "fallbackLocale": "de"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This `manifest.json` configuration is only supported since UI5 1.77.**

**For lower releases there is apparently no application-level configuration.**